# Extra filter the SharePoint list view using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, jquery, csom, jsom

I am retrieving items from a SharePoint list view. I want to further filter the CAML query to give the only items modified in last 24 hours.
 Here is my code

```
        function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText) 
 {
  var today = new Date();
  var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText +'<Geq><FieldRef Name="Modified"/><Value Type="DateTime">today-1</Value></Geq></Query></View>';
  var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
  var queryPayload = {  
           'query' : {
                  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                  'ViewXml' : viewXml  
           }
};

 return executeJson(url,"POST",null,queryPayload);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You filter would need to be something like that:

`<Geq><FieldRef Name="Modified"/><Value Type="DateTime"><Today Offset="-1" /></Value></Geq>`

Edit: Sorry, my answer was solely targeting the filter by date issue. Depending on what you provide as `queryText` parameter, you will need to add an extra `And` operator, as pointed out by Damjan Tomic in the comments:

- if it is an extra filter, like `<Eq><FieldRef Name='Foo' /><Value Type='Text'>Bar</Value></Eq>`, you will need to add the `And` or another boolean operator to combine the two filters together.
- if it is an `OrderBy` or another `Query` child element, this is fine.

In both cases however, you are missing the `Where` element  which is where filters should be defined.

So, if you pass your OrderBy as the `queryText` parameter you should have that :

`var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText +'<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today Offset="-1" /></Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>';`

If you pass another filter, you will have to do that :

`var viewXml = '<View><Query><Where><And>' + queryText +'<Geq><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today Offset="-1" /></Value></Geq></And></Where></Query></View>';`

Comment: Besides this the query should be changed to Include <And> tag. The whole line should look like this: var viewXml = '<View><Query><And>' + queryText +'<Geq><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-1" /></Value></Geq></And></Query></View>';

Comment: This is the Final CAML "<View><Query><And><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy><Geq><FieldRef Name="Modified" /><Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="-1" /></Value></Geq></And></Query></View>" but it returns all the items i get items from 2014. I am looking for items that was modified in 2/8/2017 or earlier.

Comment: Thanks to @DamjanTomic for pointing out a potential issue with combining filters through the use of the `queryText` parameter.